# Find position first occurence of an array of strings in a string

Tags: php, arrays, string

PHP has a function `strpos()` for finding the position of the first instance of a given value in a string.  Is there a way to do this with a needle that is an array of strings?  It would give the first occurence:

```
$str = '1st and 3rd';

str_array_pos($str, array('st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th')) //would return 1 because of 'st'
```

Comment: You could `foreach` over the needle array, do the `strpos()` and save the results in an array. You're looking for the `min()` of all the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write one yourself:

```
function str_array_pos($string, $array) {
  for ($i = 0, $n = count($array); $i < $n; $i++)
    if (($pos = strpos($string, $array[$i])) !== false)
      return $pos;
  return false;
}
```

By the way, the return value in your example should be 0 and not 1 since array indices start at 0.

Comment: This doesn't always return the position of the first occurence of any of the needle strings.

Comment: I agree with svens, this still won't be correct if another array element before the correct one also occurs in the string. For instance: str_array_pos('123', array('3', '2', '1')) returns 2 instead of 0, as it should.

Answer (score 1):

[array_search()](http://id2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) will do that, test with `===false`.

Comment: On second thought, I don't think this will work for your situation.  @Casablanca - noticed right when you were commenting, yours is definitely the correct way, have a +1.