# Can't search an array in PHP in_array for the presence of multiple needles

Tags: php, arrays

When giving PHP `in_array` an array of values I want to search for, it does not work.  Although the documentation specifies that you can give a *`mixed`* needle.

So basically I want to test for the presence of multiple terms as the value of an array - is there a reason this is not working, and can anyone suggest another way of doing this?

Comment: Something like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330402/find-position-first-occurence-of-an-array-of-strings-in-a-string ?

Comment: It's mixed because you can search for objects, strings, ints, bools, etc in an array - but it still only searches for a single needle. Use array_intersect() as explained below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mixed doesn't mean more than one needle, it refers to types.  It's documentation talk for more than one possible type.

Answer (score 3):

For something like searching an array $haystack for multiple $needles that are all strings or numbers, you can use `array_intersect($array1, $array2, ...)`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

It should work for mixed types also.

Answer (score 1):

When the documentation says `mixed` it means it can accept multiple types, e.g. `int`, `float`, `string`. Though the docs should say exactly which types are valid.

Comment: I believe it can take an `array` too, but the important part is it won't be an array of needles, it will be looking for an array that equals the one you passed.

Comment: @Renesis My list of multiple types was just an example. I didn't actually go read the documentation :P

Comment: doc for a particular function will explain whats allowed, but "mixed" doesn't represent any precise set of types

Comment: @jon_darkstar I know, it was meant to be an example only.