# Checking multiple variables with strpos PHP?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a simple search box that uses `strpos`to check if the entered keyword makes a match with a variable. I have this working perfectly, however I can't seem to get it to work with multiple variables. Also I can't work out how to get it to output which variable has made the match.

I thought something along the lines of this would work for checking multiple variables but I was sadly mistaken:

```
$pos = strpos($mystring1, $mystring2, $findme);
```

If anyone can help here that would be great, this is the code I currently have working for one variable.

**PHP**

```
<?
if(isset($_POST["searchString"])) {
    $mystring1 = 'how are you today';
    $mystring2 = 'hello what is your name';

    $findme = $_POST["searchString"];
    $pos = strpos($mystring1, $findme);

    if ($pos !== false) {
         //found
    } else {
         //not found
    }
}
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="test.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="searchString">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can it be an array rather than variables? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932438/search-for-partial-value-match-in-an-array

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/a/34365357/2263631

Comment: the 3th parameter of strpos is an integer with an offset. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this.

```
<?
if(isset($_POST["searchString"])) {
    $mystring1 = 'how are you today';
    $mystring2 = 'hello what is your name';

    $findme = $_POST["searchString"];
    $pos = strpos($mystring1, $findme);
    $pos2 = strpos($mystring2, $findme);

    if ($pos !== false && $pos2 !== false) {
         //found in both strings
    } else if ($pos !== false || $pos2 !== false) {
         //found in 1 of the 2 strings
    } else {
         //not found
    }


    if ($pos !== false) {
         //found in string 1
    } 
    if ($pos2 !== false) {
         //found in string 2 
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: This has worked very well, thanks you. Is there a way to make this work so it's not case sensitive?

Comment: strtolower() on both variables that you are compating.
mb_strtolower() on both variables that you are comparing if you use unicode.

Comment: Or just use `stripos()`, of course.