# php regex vs strpos for accuracy

Tags: php, regex

I have read through other posts comparing the two functions. `strpos()` and `preg_match()`. I understand that `strpos()` is the way to go if you know the exact string your looking for but what if the search subject occurs within the string.

```
$string = 'Honda 1974 1975 CB200 T Front ATK Wheel Hub w/ Brake Disc Rotor 18" x 1.60 Straight!';
```

I need to look for the CB200 and a bunch of other similar models such as CB1000, CR250, CR125 and so on.

If I used

```
preg_match('/^.*\b(c{1}b{1}2{1}0{1}0{1})\b.*$/i',$string)
```

I would get that exact string with nothing in front or behind it but `strpos($string,'CB200')` would find matches no matter what is in front or behind the searched subject.
Example: `Honda FrontCB200ATK Wheel Hub`. If that is a part number then then `strpos()` would fail. Can I make `strpos()` more accurate or would I need to use `preg_match()` in this situation? Giving up the speed of `strpos()`. The script will compare up to 10,000 `$string`'s at each execution having multiple conditions to follow in each comparison.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896587/strpos-with-multiple-needles Not exactly what you're talking about, but it might help you sort out a more elegant solution. Can't answer about improving the accuracy of str[i]pos() though.

Comment: @r3mus Well, Thanks for the link. I am tired of reading about `strpos()` and `preg_match()`. seems like i just keep reading the same stuff. Talked to the client and the models are really unique so I will use `str_pos()` non-case sensitive since the client states that all models will be in capitol letters.

Comment: This is what i ended up using:   `(strpos($data[$i]['title'], 'CB1000') !== false) ? $data[$i]['category_id']=123 : '';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone has a different opinion on something, and the best method for comparing is one of those things.

I would most likely prefer to use [`strpos()`](https://www.php.net/strpos) over [`preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) because regular expressions are generally more expensive. Both of these functions are quick, but if you are worried about performance then you should use `strpos()` to test for a string in this case.

The documentation for `preg_match()` clearly states:

> Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use strpos() or strstr() instead as they will be faster.

If you are wanting to use `preg_match()` I would rewrite your expression to something like the following.

```
preg_match('/\b(?:cb[12]000?|cr[12][25][50])\b/i', $string);
```

Comment: I decided to go with `strpos()` for that reason alone, the regex would be more accurate but in this situation I don't think I need to worry about that. I'm just concerned that `strpos()` would find a match within a word. **EX: FrontCB200ATK Wheel Hub** **EX2: Honda 1974 1975 CB200 T Front ATK Wheel Hub**. The `preg_match()` would only match the correct one `strpos()` would match both. `$needle='CB200'`

Answer (score 0):

Because of the accuracy of preg_match() I tend to use preg_match specially for form validation.