# How to find the first occurance of a few different Strings in a String in PHP

Tags: php, string, strpos

I have a String that always starts with many As, Bs or Cs and then at one point changes to Ns, Ss and Ts. I need to find the position where it changes and seperate it there.

```
Examples: "AAABCBACAANNNTTT", "BCBATTNTT", "AAABCBACAASSSSSS"

Output I want: "AAABCBACAA", "NNNTSTT";   "BCBA","TTNTT";   "AAABCBACAA","SSSSSS"
```

Now of course the position where to split would be quite easy to find with strpos if it were only one letter, like:

```
$string = "AAABCBACAANNNTTT";
echo(strpos($string, "S")); //Return: 13
```

To do it with the 3 letters, I tried the following:

```
$string = "AAABCBACAANNNTTT";
echo(min(strpos($string, "N"), strpos($string, "S"), strpos($string, "T"))); //Return:
```

The problem with this is when a letter doesn't exist in a String it will give out an empty result.

I also found a similar question but the "best answer" doesn't actually work, like 2 commenters on the answer note:

[Find position first occurence of an array of strings in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330402/find-position-first-occurence-of-an-array-of-strings-in-a-string)

Comment: The problem is that `strpos` returns `false` when the character is not found. And `min` works with numeric representations when comparing, so `false` will have the same "weight" as a zero and will almost certainly be the returned value. You should look into `preg_split`.

Comment: You could just do what the first comment under the question there suggests, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330402/find-position-first-occurence-of-an-array-of-strings-in-a-string#comment4706378_4330402 - loop over your letters that you are looking for, put the str_pos result into an array if it is _not_ false, and then feed that array to `min` …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with strpos and min function:

```
function str_array_pos($string, $array) {
    $pos = strlen($string);
    foreach($array as $char) {
        if($p = strpos($string, $char)) {
            $pos = min($pos, $p);
        }
    }
    
    return $pos < strlen($string) ? $pos : false;
}
```

This will give you the split position by looking up the positions for each provided character and return the min position or false if there is none of the characters in the string.

Input Array: `["N", "S", "T"]`

Input Strings: `"AAABCBACAANNNTTT", "BCBATTNTT", "AAABCBACAASSSSSS"`

Outputs: `10, 4, 10`

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to keep the structure you proposed, this could work:

```
<?php
  $string = "AAABCBACAANNNTTT";
  $first = (min(strpos($string, "N") ?: PHP_INT_MAX, strpos($string, "S") ?: PHP_INT_MAX, strpos($string, "T") ?: PHP_INT_MAX));
  $str1 = substr($string, 0, $first);
  $str2 = substr($string, $first);
?>
```